# Liter/100 km or km/Liter used in Italian?

Tags: word-usage

In America we say the fuel economy of car as miles/gallon (miles per gallon). I know in some countries people use Liter/100 km (liter per 100 km). Some countries use km/Liter (km per liter).

My question is: which format Italian people use?

L/100 km or km/L?

Thanks.

Comment: The answer is km/l. But the true question is: is this a question about Italian language?

Comment: Usually it is km/l, but it's also common to use liters per 100 km (especially in brochures about cars). I don't think it's a question about the Italian language, though, nor “Italian culture” at large.

Comment: Personally, I think this is borderline acceptable. If one had the necessary time and resources, it could even be interesting to search a corpus of Italian texts and to see how the use has changed in time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd say both.

The traditional way is km/l, for instance in such questions as: «Quanti chilometri fa con un litro?» («How many kilometres does it do with one litre?»).

But, perhaps as a result of foreign cars and customs, even a classical Italian magazine such as *Quattoruote* gives its data in “litri per 100km” (see [here](http://www.quattroruote.it/auto/ford/b-max/b-max-16-105-cv-powershift-plus-112135201510) for a random example).

Comment: I guess Quattroruote does not dare translate the l/100km data provided by manufacturers into km/l data, because of the rounding and error (confidence) interval problems that would arise. The precise translation of values would be too cumbersome to read, the approximate translation could potentially lead to disputes.

Comment: @WalterTross: Yes, it's very likely.

Comment: Also the car display on even Italian cars like Fiat show instant and average consumption as l/km, not km/l